# How to download binary file through axios get method in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using axios get method to download a binary file. I am able to download all the files but only csv file is supporting here. Other files like png, jpg, xlxs are not displaying. Here is the message.[image]

```
 async function getdownloadRow(fileName, filePath) {
      const tokenRes = await getToken();
      const response = await axios.get(
        `url?file_path=${filePath}&file_name=${fileName}`, 
        {
          responseType: 'arraybuffer',
          headers: {
            Authorization: tokenRes.token!,
          },
        }
      );
      return response;
    }
    
    const downloadRow = (getData) => {
        getdownloadRow(getData.file_name, getData.file_path ).then((res: any) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', getData.file_name); 
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        });
      }  
    
    <button>
      onClick={(e) => {
           e.stopPropagation();
           downloadRow(record);
      }}
    </button>
```

Comment: what are you sending in this getData.file_name ?

Comment: I am getting the file_name from backend.

Comment: check it for if it is coming in the form 'template.xlsx' or some other extension

Comment: file_name and extension are coming as required

Answer (score 0):

Here i got the solution. Instead of calling axios.get method pass the url in anchor tag. It will download and display all file extensions as well.

```
<a href={`${url}?file_path=${record.file_path}&file_name=${record.file_name}`}>
   Download me 
</a>
```